# Spring data jpa nested transaction rollback not deleting insert?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I try to insert 2 records in my database in a transaction. The second insert fails but in the rollback the first insert is not deleted:

```
   @Resource
      private WebMessageRep rep; //<-- extends JpaRepository

@Transactional
  public void test() {
    WebMessage wm = new WebMessage(.valid params.);
    wm = rep.save(wm);//<-- save is crud save which is transactional by default
    WebMessage wm2 = new WebMessage(.invalid params.);
    rep.save(wm2);
  }
```

(i also tried replacing the save method with:
jpaContext.getEntityManagerByManagedType(WebMessage.class).persist(wm);
so that i don't use the crud save, but the problem still exist)

I enabled transaction logging to see what is going on, i discovered:

Before calling test() a new transaction is created because @transactional annotaion:

```
Creating new transaction with name [com..data.webmessage.WebMessageServiceImpl.test]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
 Opened new EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
```

Calling first save, which sees the first transaction:

```
Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
```

Second save sees also the first transaction:

```
Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com..shared.WebMessage#107]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=1} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])] for JPA transaction
2017-02-22 14:07:22,000 [           main] DEBUG orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager             - Participating in existing transaction
```

When exiting test() a commit is done:

```
 Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[EntityKey[com..shared.WebMessage#108], EntityKey[com..shared.WebMessage#107]],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=2} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
```

It fails:

```
    Column 'text' cannot be null
 HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
HHH000346: Error during managed flush [org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement]
    Initiating transaction rollback after commit exception
```

Rolling back:

```
Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(PersistenceContext[entityKeys=[],collectionKeys=[]];ActionQueue[insertions=ExecutableList{size=0} updates=ExecutableList{size=0} deletions=ExecutableList{size=0} orphanRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionCreations=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionRemovals=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionUpdates=ExecutableList{size=0} collectionQueuedOps=ExecutableList{size=0} unresolvedInsertDependencies=null])]
```

The strange thing is that the first inserted record is still in my database (mysql).

Not sure if it means anything but at commit we have:
insertions=ExecutableList{size=2}
but on rollback it is:
insertions=ExecutableList{size=0}

Does anybody know why it is not rolling back the first insert?

My transaction config is quite simple:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Firing up my debugger revealed that my transaction is not active anymore when an rollback is attempted. Let me explain:

[JpaTransactionManager.java]

```
@Override
    protected void doRollback(DefaultTransactionStatus status) {
        JpaTransactionObject txObject = (JpaTransactionObject) status.getTransaction();
        if (status.isDebug()) {
            logger.debug("Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [" +
                    txObject.getEntityManagerHolder().getEntityManager() + "]");
        }
        try {
            EntityTransaction tx = txObject.getEntityManagerHolder().getEntityManager().getTransaction();
            if (tx.isActive()) {
                tx.rollback();
            }
        }
        catch (PersistenceException ex) {
            throw new TransactionSystemException("Could not roll back JPA transaction", ex);
        }
        finally {
            if (!txObject.isNewEntityManagerHolder()) {
                // Clear all pending inserts/updates/deletes in the EntityManager.
                // Necessary for pre-bound EntityManagers, to avoid inconsistent state.
                txObject.getEntityManagerHolder().getEntityManager().clear();
            }
        }
    }
```

The tx.isActive() in above code returns false, this means no rollback is executed.

Now the big question is why is my transaction not active anymore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well it seems the problem was mysql, tables generated by spring data jpa are of type myisam.

It seems that myisam goes wonky when using some types of transactions.

I converted my table to innodb and now it works: all inserted rows are deleted when transaction fails and transaction is rolledback. This doesn't happen when table is of type myisam.